# How can I terminated the program when nextInt equals zero?

Tags: java, arraylist

I populate an `Arraylist<Integer>` with palindromic numbers.  I then retrieve a user-specified element from the list via its `get()` method, and print that number.  I am trying to use a `while` loop to allow the user to select multiple elements, until he enters "0", but instead the program exits after the first selection.  How can I make it repeat?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> str = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        int a = i;
        int b = inverse(a);

        if (a == b) {
            str.add(a);
        }
    }

    int num = cin.nextInt();
    do {
        int getnum = str.get(num - 1);

        System.out.println(getnum);
    }
    while(num == 0);
}

public static int inverse(int x) {
    int inv = 0;

    while (x > 0) {
        inv = inv * 10 + x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
    }
    return inv;
}
```

Comment: FYI: If you enter a `num` is less than 0 or greater than 1000, your `str.get()` function will throw an exception.

Comment: but I enter with nextInt so str.get(nextInt) would be get what ı want to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop test should probably be `while` it's not equal to zero. Also, you need to get `num` again.

```
// int num = cin.nextInt();
int num;
do{
    num = cin.nextInt();
    System.out.println("num is " + num);
    if (num > 0 && num <= str.size()) {
      System.out.println(str.get(num - 1));
    }
} while(num != 0);
```